# How to update this Association?

Tags: programming, associations

I have the following association, assoc:

```
assoc = <|{0} -> {1}, {1} -> {2, 3, 5, 7}, {2} -> {4, 9},  {1, 1} -> {<|{2, "p"} -> {6}|>, <|{3, "p"} -> {15}|>}, {3} -> {8}|>
```

This assoc was built as follows:

```
init := <| {0} -> {1} |>
nPtL[ps_, n_] := ps -> {n}
nAPL[as_, ls_] := Association[as, ls]
assoc = nAPL[init, nPtL[{1}, 2]];
assoc[{1}] = Append[assoc[{1}], 3];
assoc = nAPL[assoc, nPtL[{2}, 4]];
assoc[{1}] = Append[assoc[{1}], 5];
tas1 = <|{2, "p"} -> {6}|>;
assoc = nAPL[assoc, nPtL[{1, 1}, tas1]];
assoc[{1}] = Append[assoc[{1}], 7];
assoc = nAPL[assoc, nPtL[{3}, 8]];
assoc[{2}] = Append[assoc[{2}], 9];
tas2 = <|{3, "p"} -> {15}|>;
assoc[{1, 1}] = Append[assoc[{1, 1}], tas2];
assoc
```

My question is as follows. How can I, efficiently, change the assoc to:

```
assoc = <|{0} -> {1}, {1} -> {2, 3, 5, 7}, {2} -> {4, 9},  {1, 1} -> {<|{2, "p"} -> {6, 10}|>, <|{3, "p"} -> {15}|>}, {3} -> {8}|>
```

That is update

```
 {1, 1} -> {<|{2, "p"} -> {6}|>, <|{3, "p"} -> {15}|>}
```

to

```
 {1, 1} -> {<|{2, "p"} -> {6,10}|>, <|{3, "p"} -> {15}|>}
```

as part of the original assoc.

Using

```
assoc[{1, 1}][[1]][{2, "p"}] caused errors.
```

Comment: `AppendTo[assoc[[Key[{1,1}], 1, Key[{2, "p"}]]], 10]`?

Comment: If I do assoc = AppendTo[assoc[[Key[{1,1}], 1, Key[{2, "p"}]]], 10] I see only {6,10}. - The question is about updating the entire structure, named assoc. But thanks for thinking along.

Comment: @niloderoock it returns `{6, 10}` only but take a look at `assoc`, and drop `assoc = ` part first.

Comment: I think I got what you mean ... Nice. - Would there be a version using Append instead of AppendTo, I wonder.

Comment: There is, but what is the point? `assoc[[Key@{1, 1}, 1, Key@{2, "p"}]] = Append[
  assoc[[Key@{1, 1}, 1, Key@{2, "p"}]],  10  ]`

Comment: Thank you. - The point? Understanding the language, etc.

Comment: The `Append` version that leaves `assoc` itself unmodified would be: `MapAt[Append[10], assoc, {Key[{1, 1}], 1, Key[{2, "p"}]}]`

Answer (score 1):

You can update the association with `AssociateTo`

```
AssociateTo[
  assoc, {{1, 1} -> {<|{2, "p"} -> {6, 10}|>, <|{3, "p"} -> {15}|>}}];
```

Which, like `AppendTo` updates the values stored in `assoc`.

```
assoc
```

`<|{0} -> {1}, {1} -> {2, 3, 5, 7}, {2} -> {4, 9}, {1, 1} -> {<|{2, "p"} -> {6, 10}|>, <|{3, "p"} -> {15}|>}, {3} -> {8}|>`

Comment: Look in the comments for the answer found by Kuba @Kuba .